# Determine gradient from past samples

Tags: regression

Again this question may be simple for you, but it is an important aspect for my classification problem. Let`s say I have 5 attributes, which are:

```
- previous_value_1
- previous_value_2
- previous_value_3
- previous_value_4
- previous_value_5
```

These attributes are generated with independent events, but I want to combine them for my classifiers therefore I need a way or statistical method to reach that goal.

These, values are actually samples that if a process is improving or getting worse. Therefore, taking average of them is meaningless, I need them to generate a function and take its derivative. But, I do not know statistical counterpart for that operation or may be simpler way to do this. To sum up, I need a way to combine these attribute values as one, and that new attribute should indicate whether it is going up or down.

I hope I managed to make some details clear to get an answer.

Also, many thanks in advance.

Comment: Let me rephrase how I understood your question: You want to measure whether the process is increasing or decreasing based on the five previous samples? Like, fitting a line to these samples and determine its slope?

Comment: @thias these attributes are past event samples, and I need to combine them to measure whether the performance is getting better or worse. But, If a manage to fit a line or function taking x axis as time where should I take the derivative? But, my question is more like statistical approach to combine these samples as one that indicates the overall improvement as positive or negative value

Comment: Why not use weighted sum of temporal changes with fading weights? Smth like this. Say, your values change: +1 then -2 then +1.1. Let weights from now to past fall like 1 .5 .25... Then index = 1*(+1.1) + .5*(-2) + .25*(+1)

Comment: @baris_a I changed the title to better reflect the content of your question. I hope that's ok with you?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't know whether this does answer your question, but here goes. I use linear regression.
(The example is in R)

As an example, I use these values

```
t=1:5;
x=c(-10, 15, 20, -5, 4);
```

for you 5 previous values sampled at time t. From your description, I assume that each value is the difference to the preceding one (indicating, whether the process increased or decreased for each sample). So to fit the line, I take the cumulative sum

```
z=cumsum(x);
```

and fit a linear regression model

```
mod=lm( z~t);
```

The result can be plotted with

```
plot(z,type="b")
lines(x,type="b",col="red")
abline(mod, col="green")
```

[image]
which gives you this plot.

The red points are the original data, the red the cumulative sum and the green line is the regression line. You can use the slope of the regression line as an indicator for the degree of in/decrease of your data-points which you get by

```
mod$coefficients[2]
```

Comment: many thanks for the answer and that is what I was looking for, also I understand the basics, also fitting to linear regression. But I do not know how to implement lm in Java. Anyways,  many thanks

Comment: You should check out the equations for linear regression, e.g. http://www.wired.com/wiredscience/2011/01/linear-regression-by-hand/ and implement them in java (really simple).

Answer (score 0):

You're looking for "Numerical Differentiation".   Here's the Wiki version:

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Numerical_differentiation

Notice under the "Higher Order Methods" section, there's a five point formula.  In your case, assuming pv_1 happens first, pv_2 happens next, .... pv_5 happens last, and the time between each step is a constant "h", the formula is:

```
slope = ((-1*pv_5) + (8*pv_4) + (-8*pv_2) + (1*pv_1)) / (12*h)
```

Also, notice that this is the derivative at the midpoint (pv_3).

Edit 10/06/2011 ============================================================

@thias: From the original question, he's using the 5 previous data values to determine if things are "going up" or "going down".  Any "outlier" will have a consistent effect on the 5 sequential calculations that use that "outlier".

The numerical derivative calculation is already noisy and noise in the data makes it worse.    My point is, most of the time, noise is "the" issue, not the method of the calculation.

The 5 point method above uses a higher order scheme to calculate the result.   It will produce more noise than my (pv_5 - pv_1)/h method in the comment section below.   It is because of this added noise that most people would choose the (pv_5 - pv_1)/h method over the 5 point method.

Comparing the (pv_5 - pv_1)/h method to your moving-window-least-squares method, the added trouble of the calculation typically provides small advantages with some additional noise.   In other words, it provides a better answer, but a lot of people go the "quick-and-easy-route"

Below is some code:

```
#Set up the parameters
set.seed(101)
n <- 100 #Number of data points
h <- 1 #Step change in time sequence
t <- 1:n #time sequence
a <- 3 #Scale for the sine wave
w <- pi/20 #Frequency for the sine wave

noi <- 2 #Multiplier for noise level

#Build the data series, then add noise
dat <- a*sin(w*t)
datn <- dat + (noi*rnorm(n))

#Calculate the actual derivative
derdat <- a*w*cos(w*t)

#Calculate the derivative using the 5 point scheme
derdat5p <- rep(NA, n)
for (i in 3:(n-2)) {
  derdat5p[i] <- ((-1*datn[i+2]) + (8*datn[i+1]) + (-8*datn[i-1]) + (1*datn[i-2])) / (12*h)
}

#Calculate the derivative using the 2 point scheme
derdat2p <- rep(NA, n)
for (i in 3:(n-2)) {
  derdat2p[i] <- (datn[i+2] - datn[i-2]) / (5*h)
}

#Fit a moving-window line to the data and extract the derivative
derdatlin <- rep(NA, n)
for (i in 3:(n-2)) {
  mod <- lm(datn[(i-2):(i+2)] ~ t[(i-2):(i+2)])
  derdatlin[i] <- as.numeric(mod$coefficients[2])
}

#Set up the plot area
par(pty="m", plt=c(0.1, 1, 0, 1), omd=c(0.1,0.9,0.1,0.9))
par(mfrow = c(2, 1))

#Plot the series
plot(datn, type="n", xaxt="n", xlab="", ylim=range(datn, dat, na.rm =TRUE), las=2)
mtext(side=3, paste("Noise Level = ", noi, sep=""), line=1, cex=2)
mtext(side=2, "f(t)", line=3)
atx <- seq(par("xaxp")[1], par("xaxp")[2], (par("xaxp")[2]-par("xaxp")[1])/par("xaxp")[3])
abline(v=atx, col="lightgray")
lines(datn, col="darkgray")
lines(dat, lwd=2, col="red")
legend("bottomright", legend=c("datn", "dat"), bg="white", lwd=c(1, 2), col=c("darkgray", "red"), cex=0.9)

#Plot the derivative of the series
plot(derdat, type="n", xaxt="n", xlab="", ylim=range(derdat, derdat5p, derdat2p, na.rm =TRUE), las=2)
mtext(side=2, "Derivative of f(t)", line=3)
atx <- seq(par("xaxp")[1], par("xaxp")[2], (par("xaxp")[2]-par("xaxp")[1])/par("xaxp")[3])
abline(v=atx, col="lightgray")
lines(derdat5p, col="darkgray")
lines(derdat2p, col="green")
lines(derdatlin, col="blue")
lines(derdat, lwd=2, col="red")
legend("bottomright", legend=c("derdat5p", "derdat2p", "derdatlin", "derdat"), bg="white", lwd=c(1, 1, 1, 2), col=c("darkgray", "green", "blue", "red"), cex=0.9)

#Place the time axis
axis(side = 1)
mtext(side=1, "t", line=1.9, cex=0.8)
```

Below is the output of the above code with the noise value `noi` set to 2.   The top graph shows the original data (in red) with noise (in gray).

The bottom graph is the calculation of the derivative.  The red line is the actual derivative.   The noisy gray line is 5-point method shown above.   The green line is the 2-point method.   And, the blue line is your moving-window-least-squares method.

Notice that there's not much difference in the 2-point method and the moving-window-least-squares method.  It depends on how you measure the noise level as to which method has "more noise".   As I stated in the comment section below, it's typically not the method that's the issue, it's the noise.

[image]

Below is another run with the noise value `noi` set to 0.2.   Your moving-window-least-squares method does a better job in the peaks/valleys than the 2-point method, but again, it depends on how you measure the noise as to which method has "more noise".

So, back to the original issue of measuring if things are "going up" or "going down", both methods are typically close enough that it doesn't matter which one is used.   The main issue is typically the level of noise.

[image]

Comment: If the samples are noisy, it might be better to first fit an analytical function (such as a linear one) and then take the derivative (i.e. linear regression). I guess that's what @baris_a meant with "statistical".

Comment: @thias: If the samples are noisy, you won't lose much by simply looking the lowest form of the solution............ (pv_5 - pv_1)/h It's rare that the choice of technique is the issue.

Comment: of course you will! You will lose all information from  sample 2-4. What if 1 and 5 are outliers?

Comment: @thias: I added my comments as an edit above.

Comment: Some of those comments appear incorrect.  For instance, outliers will have different effects on the windows in which they appear: they tend to have more leverage when at the ends of windows than in the middles, depending on what technique is used.  The method really does matter: for instance, Sen's method will be resistant to isolated outliers (no more than one per window), whereas the polynomial interpolators will be exquisitely sensitive to outliers.  (This method uses the median of all 10 pairwise slopes attained between the 5 elements of any window.)

Comment: @whuber: You're right, my use of the phrase "consistent effect" was sloppy.  However, I've tried every method I can find, including the Theil-Sen method, and for time series models similar to what is discussed above, the "improvement" over the 2-point method and moving-window-least-squares method was minimal.   Just add it to the above code (package mblm) and you'll see what I mean.